# custom module + cron

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cron

I have a little problem (which should be easy to solve), with a custom module I try to execute through crontab. For now, the only thing it is supposed to do is to print a log entry in dev.log file. Unfortunately, it doesn't, that's why I look for some help.

Below is how I've created my module.

**app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Cronmodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Cronmodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Cronmodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mycompany/Cronmodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Cronmodule>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Cronmodule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <cronmodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Cronmodule_Model</class>
            </cronmodule>                         
        </models>
    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mycompany_cronmodule>
                <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>cronmodule/observer::test</model></run>
            </mycompany_cronmodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mycompany/Cronmodule/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Mycompany_Cronmodule_Model_Observer {

    public function test(){
        Mage::log("TEST success", null, "dev.log");
    }
}
```

I have configured my windows task manager to execute cron.php every 5 minutes which works perfectly to send Magento emails (I run a local instance on a local windows with wamp).

Do you have any hints ?

Comment: Is it needed to do crontab -e and enter the cron job in this or no? I am trying to copy your solution but still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that I have nothing wrong in my code, after cleaning the cache, I can see in the table magentocron_schedule a lot of Cronmodule tasks pending (and some executed). I also have my output in my log file which is perfect.

Thanks to this post to give me the hint to clean the cache: [Can't get cron job to work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24162/cant-get-cron-job-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

For run the cron job,you need to add time interval properly

```
<schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

to

```
<schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

Comment: As for me <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr> also workable

Comment: <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule> is a valid interval. It means execute the task every minutes.